# deployJava.js redirects to Java.com even JRE is present in machine

Tags: java, javascript, oracle, applet, deployjava

Our application has an applet in a web page. To render it we used deployJava.js (recommended approach by Oracle). But it is redirecting to Java.com, even correct (minimum) JRE version is installed in the machine.

As per documentation it should redirect to Java.com, if no JRE installed or minimum JRE version is not met.

Below is the code:

```javascript
var attributes = {codebase:'/OrcWeb/appletFiles/',
    code:'com.comName.appName.applet.UploadDisplayApplet.class',
    archive:'appName-applet-1.0.jar',
    width:1100, height:350} ;
var parameters = {fontSize:16} ;
var version = '1.6' ;
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
```

Comment: It is not as simple as you think it is. You do not need 'a' runtime, you need the runtime which matches the browser's architecture. If you are using a 32 bits browser and have a 64 bits Java runtime installed, you will still be redirected because from the perspective of the browser environment you do not have a matching 32 bits Java plugin yet.

Comment: I heard recently that the script no longer supports anything lower than 1.7.  Try `var version = '1.7+' ;`.